# What is the best method to serve large GeoJSON data in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I would like to know about the best method to serve large GeoJSON data in OpenLayers. I am using extent-based loading and clearing the source when it is in out of extent. But still it is hanging while serving with big GeoJSON. I am accessing GeoJSON from GeoServer and ArcGIS Server based on extent.

Comment: I think vector tiles are the solution. OpenLayers supports MVT.

Comment: We needs to convert GeoJSON to MVT in client side or render MVT from Server? Because I need to use both Arcserver and GeoServer layers.

Comment: Best for what purpose?

Comment: I need to display geojson Layers into my map with editing capabilities and view purpose.

Comment: @MuhammedSahal MVT must generate on server side. GeoServer supported MVT. ArcServer it seems to me too, I not sure. For editing - you need additional logic, to get full feature geometry for editing from server. MVT is not for editing, only for fast rendering.

Comment: Also have a look at [geojson-vt](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt) and it's integration in [Openlayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson-vt.html?q=geojson).